# Can we mount/unmount a device/disk/usb on Mac using Cocoa Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, mount, disk, unmount

I am trying to mount a device that was ejected/unmounted by this API

`unmountAndEjectDevice(at:)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1530469-unmountandejectdevice

but I am unable to find an API that can help me remount the disc that was ejected by the user or by that API.

A couple of things I discovered, are using Disk Arbitration API or by using IO Kit Family Storage but I am not sure how to use them and IOKit is a low-level api, so, I don't want to mess with that either unless it's the only way.

A last resort solution for me is using diskutil but I want to know if there is a cocoa swift way of doing it